# Ajax success and error return error but code executed

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why my code run from error place:

```
error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

In backend code clean working..
I get result file upload successfull but fronend run code from error block

front end code:

```
                    var file_data = $("#profile_photo").prop("files")[0];
                    var form_data = new FormData();                  
                    form_data.append("file", file_data);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "upload.php",
                        dataType: 'script',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: form_data,                         
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }, 
                        error: function(e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                   })
```

Comment: Can you please try to explain more clearly? You should probably check the server response for errors using Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 Network tab.

Comment: What does the error say? It could be a multitude of reasons.

Comment: I dont think there is error, but you can see file_data is correct value.

Also you can set contentType :'multipart/form-data'

Comment: console.log(file_data) output: http://pastebin.com/DhbUPF1P

Comment: `error: function(e) {
                                console.log(e);
                            }` output: http://pastebin.com/Wp8rd1ks